# Can't open a new html page by clicking on an image [flask/html/python]

Tags: python, html, flask

I got a simple flask server that manages a login page.
The webpage works fine: login, logout, register, etc
After the login page there is a "home.html" page with 3 images. What I'm trying to do is to open a second webpage by clicking on the image.
The page I'm trying to load is called "output.html" and it is inside the folder "templates"

Folder structure:

- webserver

  - instance
  - website

    - images
    - static
    - templates

      - base.html
      - home.html
      - login.html
      - main.html
      - output.html
      - sign_up.html
- **init**.py
- auth.py
- models.py

Flask script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, send_from_directory, request
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user, LoginManager, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length, ValidationError

app = create_app()
#app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisisasecretkey'


login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(validators=[
                           InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)], render_kw={"placeholder": "Username"})

    password = PasswordField(validators=[
                             InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=20)], render_kw={"placeholder": "Password"})

    submit = SubmitField('Register')
    
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(validators=[
                           InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)], render_kw={"placeholder": "Username"})

    password = PasswordField(validators=[
                             InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=20)], render_kw={"placeholder": "Password"})

    submit = SubmitField('Login')

#@app.route("/images/<path:filename>")
#def serve_image(filename):
#    return send_from_directory("images", filename)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/output', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def output():
    return render_template('output.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def dashboard():
    return render_template('dashboard.html')

@app.route('/logout', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm()
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.run()
    app.run()
```

HTML side:

```
 <div id="Ohm" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Escolha um dos três circuitos</h3>
    <p>Clique OK para seguir</p>
    <div>
      <img 
        src="../images/circuit_R1.png" 
        width="30%" 
        height="auto" 
        alt="circuito R1" 
        class="responsive" 
        onclick="redirecionarPaginaEAcionar('10010101', '/output')" 
        style="cursor: pointer;" >
      
        <img 
          src="../images/circuit_R2.png" 
          width="30%" 
          height="auto" 
          alt="circuito R1" 
          class="responsive" 
          onclick="accionarReles('01011011')" 
          style="cursor: pointer;" >

(...)

 <script>
    function accionarReles(parametro)
      {
     (...)
    }
    
    function redirecionarPaginaEAcionar(parametro, url) {
      accionarReles(parametro); // Chama a função accionarReles com o parâmetro especificado
      window.location.href = url; // Redireciona para a URL especificada
    }
      
  </script>
```

So, after I run the server and login, the script calls home.html.
When click in the image another html page should be open: output.html.
However, as the program is I get an 404 error page not found.

But, if I replace output with login, which is a page that is in the same folder, everything is right.

I can't find the error/mistake and I can't open another page unless is "login.html" even if I move it outside "templates"
So, I need some help to find the mistake

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you should use the `url_for` function provided by Flask to generate the URL for the `output` route

```html
<img 
    src="../images/circuit_R1.png" 
    width="30%" 
    height="auto" 
    alt="circuito R1" 
    class="responsive" 
    onclick="redirecionarPaginaEAcionar('10010101', '{{ url_for('output') }}')" 
    style="cursor: pointer;">
```

By using `url_for('output')`, Flask will generate the correct URL for the `output` route

Comment: Thank you for your help but it won't work.

This line gives two errors: missing ","

If I put the "," in the places...

onclick="redirecionarPaginaEAcionar('10010101', '{{ url_for(',output,') }}')" 


...the result is an "5000 Internal Server Error"